# Listview to datatable

Tags: c#, database, winforms, listview, datatable

I have a listview and I NEED to load the rows and columns into datatable.

I have tried as follows

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    table.Columns.Add(item.ToString()); 
    foreach (var it in item.SubItems) 
        dt.Rows.Add(it.ToString()); 
}
```

When I retrieved the rowcount and columncount then I got number of rows as column count and number of column as rowcount

dont know what's going on..
please help me
best regards
Bunzitop

Comment: to what your listView is bound? you have that source?

Answer (score 1):

its a long time ago, but someone will probably struggle about this in the future, 
so here is my solution to convert a ListView to a DataTable:

```
DataTable dtZeitplan = new DataTable();
foreach (ColumnHeader chZeitplan in lvZeitplan.Columns)
{
    dtZeitplan.Columns.Add(chZeitplan.Text);
}
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvZeitplan.Items)
{
    DataRow row = dtZeitplan.NewRow();
    for(int i = 0; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
    {
        row[i] = item.SubItems[i].Text;
    }
    dtZeitplan.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it so wrong. You need `1 + listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Count` columns in your `DataTable` (the 1 is for ListViewItem and others are subitems) and `listView1.Items.Count` number of rows. Therefore your code should be like this:

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
{
       dt.Columns.Add();
       foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi in listView1.Items[0].SubItems)
              dt.Columns.Add();
       //now we have all the columns that we need, let's add rows
       foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
       {
              List<string> row = new List<string>();
              row.Add(item.ToString());
              foreach (var it in item.SubItems)
                   row.Add(it.ToString());
              //Add the row into the DataTable
              dt.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("MODUL", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("ACIKLAMA", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("UZUNLUK", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("GENISLIK", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("MIKTAR", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(listView2.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ItemsSource property and System.Data classes (ADO.Net) to bind a listview to a datatable and vise-verse (what you want).  The following code will give you a datatable from an existing bound ListView control.

```
DataView theDataView = (DataView)theListView.ItemsSource;
DataTable theDataTable = theDataView.Table;
```

Manish Mishra asked what your listview control is bound to.  This is a very good question.  My answer assumes it is already bound to a datatable.

Comment: according to your answer, i got this exception  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[ClinicManagment.Statistics.Doctor]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.

Answer (score 0):

Working code from VB.Net: Just replace your listview name with "LVActions"

```
        Dim it As Integer = 0
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        For it = 0 To LVActions.Items(0).SubItems.Count - 1
            Dim DCOL As New DataColumn(LVActions.Columns(it).Text)
            dt.Columns.Add(DCOL)
        Next
        For it = 0 To LVActions.Items.Count - 1
            Dim DROW As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            For j As Integer = 0 To LVActions.Items(it).SubItems.Count - 1
                DROW(LVActions.Columns(j).Text) = LVActions.Items(it).SubItems(j).Text
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(DROW)
        Next
```